# How is the best way to model this data structure using loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I'd like to have the following data structure:

```
Blog
{
  name: "blog test",
  description: "description",
  additionalFields: {
    fieldExample: {
      property1: "test",
      property2: "test",
      property3: "test"
    },
    fieldExample2: {
      property1: "test",
      property2: "test",
      property3: "test"
    }
  }
}
```

Being "fieldExamples" dynamically created and "property1", "property2", "property3" fixed.

Using loopbackjs and embedded models, how is the best way to model the field "additionalFields"?

I've read about embedded models and relations in the documentation, but I couldn't figure out how to model this. I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I think embedsMany can do the trick. As this [link](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Embedded-models-and-relations.html#define-the-relation-in-json-1) said the solution can be something like the following code:

**common/models/blog.json**

```
{
  "name": "Blog",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "additionalFields": {
      "type": "embedsMany",
      "model": "AdditionalFields",
      "property": "additionalFields",
      "options": {
        "validate": true,
        "forceId": false
      }
    }
  }
```

**common/models/additionalFields.json**

```
{
  "name": "AdditionalFields",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "property1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "property2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "property3": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
```

The only difference between this code and your sample will be additionalFields. In your code, it is an object, but the output of the above code will be an array for additionalFields. I'm not sure is it acceptable in your code or not.

If you need to save fieldExample as well, I think you can simply add a filed in AdditionalFields model and save the value of fieldExample in it.